# Javascript: Understanding variables wrapped in functions

Tags: javascript

Trying to wrap my head around Javascript scope and looking for someone to explain what's happening in the following. Hoping it'll help not just me...

```
var foo = {
  bar: {}
};
(function(foo, bar) {
  foo.bar = 'a';
  bar = 'b';

}(foo, foo.bar))

console.log(foo.bar) // prints 'a', not 'b', how come?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define two variables:

```
function(foo, bar)
```

You pass two values into them:

```
}(foo, foo.bar))
```

The value of `foo` is a reference to an object (that object has a property `bar` whose value is a reference to a different object)

The value of the variable `bar` is a reference to that second object.

```
foo.bar = 'a';
```

You overwrite the `bar` property of the first object with the string `'a'`. `foo.bar` is no longer a reference to the second object. The value of `bar` is still a reference to the second object.

```
bar = 'b';
```

You overwrite the local `bar` variable with the string `'b'`. There are now no references to the second object left. The second object will be garbage collected.

```
console.log(foo.bar)
```

You output the value of the `bar` property of the object that the value of `foo` is a reference to. This is `'a'` since you modified the value of that property in the function.

Comment: Not fully correct. Try this: `var foo = { bar: {} }; (function(bar) { bar = 'b'; }(foo.bar)); console.log(foo.bar);`

Comment: @SimonSimCity — That just removes all instances of modifying "the first object", so when you console.log it you get the second object (because you didn't overwrite the bar *property* of the first object). How does that conflict with my answer?

Comment: @Scimonster, For me it returns `{}` - not the (by me) awaited `'b'`.

Comment: @SimonSimCity I expected the `{}`, because again, it's overwriting the local variable, not the reference to `foo.bar`.

Comment: @Quentin, you said, that the call of `foo.bar` kills the reference ... that said, the reference of the variable `bar` should still exist, or when does the reference get changed into a copy?

Comment: @SimonSimCity — As I said in the answer, you are overwriting the *local variable `bar`* with the string `'b'`. You aren't overwriting a property of an object. In your version of the code, you don't even have a reference to that object to modify.

Comment: @SimonSimCity — The value of the `bar` variable starts out as being a reference to the second object. You overwrite that value with a string. You aren't backtracking along the reference to modify the property where you got the value (i.e. the reference) from.

Comment: @Quentin, Ok - What so about this one? `var foo = { bar: {} }; (function(foo, bar) { foo.bar = 'b'; console.log(bar); }(foo, foo.bar))` - I do not modify `bar` - so it should still be a reference to `foo.bar`, as I suggested by your explanation ...

Comment: @SimonSimCity — What about it? You overwrite the `bar` property of the first object, then log the value of the local `bar` variable, which is still a reference to the second object (because you haven't overwritten it).

Comment: @SimonSimCity – The local `bar` variable is **never** a reference to `foo.bar`. You can't have a reference to a property. `foo.bar` and `bar` are both references to the same object. They can be overwritten independently. There is no connection between `foo.bar` and `bar` other than that they are sometimes given the same value.

Answer (score 4):

`foo` is an object, which is passed by reference. `bar` is passed by value. When `bar` is overwritten, it loses the relation to `foo.bar`. Hence, `foo.bar` is "a"`, which is what it was set to in the function.

```
var foo = {
  bar: {}
};
(function(foo, bar) {
    // foo is {bar:{}}
    // bar is {}
  foo.bar = 'a';
    // now foo is {bar:'a'}
  bar = 'b';
    // now bar is 'b'
    // bar has no relation to foo.bar anymore

}(foo, foo.bar))

console.log(foo.bar) // prints 'a', not 'b', how come?
```

Comment: I think OP is asking that `foo` inside the function is not equal to the `foo` outside of function scope.. it should print `{}` but not `a`. I might be wrong though..

Comment: `foo` refers to the same object in both scopes.

Comment: `foo.bar` (the argument to the function) is an object as well. Neither the `foo` nor the `bar` parameters are passed by reference